# Networking cost GCP between Mongodb Atlas with internal IP(VPC) between same regions / zones

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, vpn, price, mongodb-atlas

Anyone know what is the **"Data Transfer cost"** of networking between an atlas GCP instance configured with GCP-VPC between the same region/zone and with a GCP compute engine?
Is it free? $ 0.01

I'm using atlas instance in GCP.
Atlas set data transfer price a $0.01/GB for the same region, but I want to reduce to 0.
So I want to create GCE and atlas instance in the same region and connecting as a Internal IP(VPC).

In [GCP-VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/), ingrass/egrass price between same zone and same regions has as "no charge"!
Anyone have tried or know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ingress traffic cost is for free.

For egress:

Traffic between **VMs** in the same **zone** is for free

Traffic between **VMs** in the same **region** costs $0.01/GB

Traffic between **VPN** and **VM** in the same **region** in for free.

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/)